Error code 1217: "Session has been closed"
I am currently studying algorithms related to VQA. I have built a circuit to calculate the cost function and optimized it using a classical optimizer. During the initial optimization iterations, everything seemed to be working fine, and the quantum computer (ibm-osaka)  was able to compute the loss function values accurately. However, I suddenly encountered an error during one of the calculations as follows:
qiskit_ibm_runtime.exceptions.IBMRuntimeError: 'Failed to run program: \'400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.quantum.ibm.com/runtime/jobs. {"errors":[{"code":1217,"message":"Session has been closed.","solution":"Reduce time between submitting subsequent jobs in a session.","more_info":"https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/errors"}]}\''

Despite my numerous attempts to resubmit the code, the problem still persists. It seems to suggest that I waited too long and the session was closed directly. How should I solve this problem? Is my porblem same as this problem?
My version is: qiskit=1.1.0, qiskit-ibm-experiment=0.4.7, qiskit-ibm-runtime=0.23.0
